# Algorithm to find optimal path and cycle with minimum score constraint as a team

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory, heuristics, np

Given a game where *K* number of coordinates exists with each coordinate carrying a score, a team of *N* players exist. Each player's goal is to collect as many points possible while minimising the distance travelled.

Once a coordinate has been visited by any player in the team, it will award zero points if revisited again.

There are two variants of this game in which each player have to devise a valid route:

- Mode 1 (Cycle), where each player will have to return to the starting point *(0,0)*
- Mode 2 (Path), where each player will start from *(0,0)* but can end the route at any point

A solution route is *only* scored based on total distance travelled.

For example:
Given one player's route `[A,B,C,D]` (where A-D are coordinates), the route will be scored like this:

```
 - Mode 1 Score = Total euclidean distance from (0,0)->A->B->C->D->(0,0)
 - Mode 2 Score = Total euclidean distance from (0,0)->A->B->C->D
```

Ultimately, the team's goal is to *minimise* the total distance travelled by all *N* players, while ensuring all players have a *collective* total score of at least *P* points.

I'm guessing that this might be related to the Travelling Salesman Problem. However, unlike in TSP where all nodes must be visited once, the game only requires the players to minimise distance travelled, as long as *score* >= *P*.

What might be a good algorithm to approximate an optimal set of routes for *N* players?

Comment: It sounds like integer programming can be an option. In fact, the per-player part of the problem would be very similar to TSP, you only have to drop the constraints that require each node to be visited. Then there are the additional constraints. For these it is not quite clear to me when a score is assigned to which player: If two players visit the same coordinate, how do you decide which player gets the score? If is not clear how you do that. It is also not clear whether this matters. If the constraint is that the *team* (as opposed to each player) must score P points then it does not matter.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the comment. The constraint in this case is by team - so long as all players score P points. So theres no competition between players. I'm not too familiar with integer programming, could you give an example on how it might look like as an algorithm?

Comment: Here is one [resource](https://neos-guide.org/content/multiple-traveling-salesman-problem-mtsp) that can be useful. You can replace the node visitation constraints with a constraint on the sum of visits, and add a constraint stating that each node is exited only if it is also visited.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Im trying to implement this in Python code, and unfortunately using a remote server solver is not an option. I dont actually need a exact solution, but an algorithm that can find one as close to the global optimum as possible. Could you give an example of how one might approximate a good route algorithmically?